# Not able to connect to mysql through java application in docker?

Tags: docker

Issue Detail

1. I have a java application running in a docker container.
2. Also mysql is running in another docker container.
3. I am trying to connect the java application to mysql using this configuration -

   > ```
   > db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   > db.url: jdbc:mysql://mysql_docker_IP:3306/Database_Name
   > db.username: user
   > db.password: password
   > ```
4. However the java application docker-container is not able to connect to the mysql-container:

**ERROR LOG**

> 2016-08-10 06:36:04 WARN JdbcServicesImpl:204 - HHH000342: Could not
>   obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

Does anybody have an idea about what the issue is?

Comment: Sure you have the correct IP address for the mysql docker container? The error message suggests you don't. What version of docker are you using? You should be able to access the container by name using the inbuilt DNS that comes in recent docker versions.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for reply... Mark can you please look at the detailed explanation/discussion of the issue at this link https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25562 and suggest help.

Comment: I thought the explanations given by "thaJeztah" were excellent. The problem here is that your issue is now spread between a stackoverflow posting and github. I strongly suggest you revise this posting with the relevent information on how you build your Mysql container. Better yet, start with the official mysql image and eliminate one possible source of error. See: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/. What was not obvious from your original postings was that you're building a bespoke image and calling it "mysql".

Answer (score 0):

- Use *mysql container name* as host name

  ```
  db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  db.url: jdbc:mysql://mysql_container_name:3306/Database_Name
  db.username: user
  db.password: password
  ```

  **Note :** Port must be the port in which mysql container runs .